# Moving payments beyond pending

Tags: paypal, payment

I am new to paypal and using a developer account at https://developer.paypal.com/.

I am submitting a product via my shopping cart to my developer paypal account where I am making the necessary payment. However, back at my website, the payment status is labelled **pending**.

How can I transition the status beyond pending to **complete** or rejected (as the case may be)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IPN to update your shopping cart, and move the payment from pending to completed.  [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.

Comment: Thanks, First time learning about this IPN. I will read about it.